# how to create a list and sum up

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and got stuck on the below:
Below is the code I am working with

```
import re

handle = open ('RegExWeek2.txt')
for line  in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        print x
```

The return from this code looks like this:

```
['7430']
['9401', '9431']
['2248', '2047']
['5517']
['3184', '1241']
['9939']
['2185', '9450', '8428']
['369']
['3683', '6442', '7654']
```

Question: how do I combine this to one list and sum up the numbers?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You may change your code like this,

```
handle = open ('RegExWeek2.txt')
num = []
for line  in handle:
    num.extend(re.findall('[0-9]+', line))
print sum(int(i) for i in num)
```

Since you're using `re.findall`, this `line.rstrip()` line is not necessary.
And also there won't be possible for x to be an empty list, since we are using `+` next to `[0-9]` (*repeats the previous token one or more times*) not `*` (*zero or more times*)

Comment: Accept an answer which helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to `rstrip`, and you should open files using `with`:

```
import re

all_numbers = []
with open('RegExWeek2.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
        for number in numbers:
            all_numbers.append(int(number))

print(sum(all_numbers))
```

This is really beginner code, and a direct translation of yours. Here's how I would write it:

```
with open('RegExWeek2.txt') as file:
    all_numbers = [int(num) for num in re.findall('[0-9]+', file.read())]
print(sum(all_numbers))
```